# Скрипт Google Apps возвращает неправильный часовой пояс

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Столкнулся с проблемой при получении данных к гугл таблицы, а именно то что происходит откат на 3 часа назад.
В настройках скрипта и таблицы стоит МСК (GMT+3) но скрипт выводит нулевой (GMT)

```
var data = getDataTest();
if (!data) {
  data = '';
}
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': data })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

function getDataTest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var shetname = sheet.getSheetByName("...");

  var result = [],
    range = 'A:B',
    values = shetname.getRange(range).getValues(),
    last_row = parseInt(shetname.getLastRow());

  for (var i = 1; i < last_row; i++) {
    result.push(values[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Вот сама таблица:

[image: 1]

И вот то как ее выводит скрипт:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо настроить манифест проекта скрипта, т.к. он как раз указывает на нужный часовой пояс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часовой пояс Таблицы

```js
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
```

Часовой пояс проекта

```js
  Session.getScriptTimeZone();
```

Вы можете сравнивать результаты этих методов для контроля за часовыми поясами.

Чтобы автоматически изменить часовой пояс проекта, необходимо использовать Google Script API [projects/updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent).

Подогнать часовой пояс Таблицы к часовому поясу проекта

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().setSpreadsheetTimeZone(Session.getScriptTimeZone());
```